# How to symbolize "roughly belongs to"?

Tags: notation, normal-distribution

Say I have a number $n$ that is a random normally distributed number. $99.73\%$ of the time this number is between -3 and 3, so it roughly belongs to the set $[-3,3]$. How could I symbolize this in a scientific paper?

Comment: There is no notation for that in set theory. It either is, or it isn't. Fuzzy set theory would be more appropriate, perhaps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would write "$N$ is Gaussian random variable with the property $P(N\in[3,3])=0.9973$."